# Show/Hide view with animation in android

Tags: android

I want to hide and show view with animation after the user touches on screen alternatively. but I have not any idea how to do that. Can anybody help me, please?

**I get the hight of view here**

```
int finalHeight = listView.getHeight(); 
ValueAnimator mAnimator = slideAnimator(finalHeight, 0);
```

**Then hide that layout**

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(start, end);

    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            // Update Height
            int value = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = listView
                    .getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = value;

            listView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
```

> I want same animation like this [Here is Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK_jr6Rf7p0)

Comment: What did you try till now?

Comment: This tutorial maybe help you : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: You should post what you've done so far.

Comment: I hide the view with animation but it doesn't come after second touch

Comment: Post your code then.

Comment: Why won't you google it ? There is a lot of examples out there

Comment: @Shaishav I update my question please check and help me

Answer (score 1):

Your hiding animation can look like this:

```
    ObjectAnimator hideAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", 0, -v.getHeight());
    hideAnim.setDuration(300);

    hideAnim.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override 
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override 
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        } 
    });
```

Your unhiding anim can look like this:

```
    ObjectAnimator unhideAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "translationY", -v.getHeight, 0);
    unhideAnim.setDuration(300);
```

Click listeners for your view:

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Overrride
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (v.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
            v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
            v.startAnimation(unhideAnim);
        } else {
            v.startAnimation(hideAnim);
        }
    }
});
```

Will only work if your view is at top of its viewgroup.

Comment: Not working for me. I want to hide horizontal `RecyclerView`

Comment: You need to share whats happening.

Comment: I used your code but `RecyclerView` is not hiding. It remains on the screen

Comment: You gotta be kidding me! Why are revealing me about RecyclerView only now! How can you expect someone to help you out of thin air with you hiding all the crucial information? VISIT HERE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry, My Mistake. But is there any solution for hiding Horizontal `RecyclerView`